# Why is empty string test failing?

Tags: string, matlab

[image]

```
 function browsePushButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)  
 % hObject    handle to browsePushButton (see GCBO)
 % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
 % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
 % show open file dialog
 [filename, pathname] = uigetfile({ '*.jpg'; '*.png';'*.bmp';'*.jpeg'; }, ...
                                'Open image', ...
                                '' ...
                                );
 % obtain image-file's path
 imagePath = strcat(pathname, filename);

 % if the imagePath is not empty...
 if (imagePath ~= '')    
    image = imread(imagePath);
    % digging out image related info
    [pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(filename) ;
    fileinfo = imfinfo(imagePath);
    FileSize1 = fileinfo.FileSize(1,1);
    width = fileinfo.Width;
    height = fileinfo.Height;
    % 
    axes(handles.imagesPictureBox);
    imshow(image);
 else
    % if the imagePath is empty, display a error message
    h = msgbox('Invalid Value', 'Error','error');
 end
```

**Error message**

```
Error using  ~= 
 Matrix dimensions must agree.
 Error in OpenFileDialogBoxTest>browsePushButton_Callback (line 91)
 if (imagePath ~= '')
 Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});
 Error in OpenFileDialogBoxTest (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
 Error in @(hObject,eventdata)OpenFileDialogBoxTest('browsePushButton_Callback',
           hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
 Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `strcmp` to compare strings

```
if ~strcmp(imagePath,'')
    ...
end
```

the *not equal* operator you used expects both character arrays to be of the same dimensions.

**EDIT:** Two more things
1.) when you get the file and path information by using `uigetfile`, keep in mind that the output can be numeric. That is the case when the user cancels the dialog. You should catch that possibility.
2.) The way you construct the absolute path from the outputs of `uigetfile` is wrong. There is a file separator, i.e. a '/' or '\' missing. I recommend using `imagePath = fullfile(pathname, filename);` instead

Answer (score 2):

First of all, that's not the right way to check if a string is empty. The [`~=` operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-comparison-with-relational-operators.html) is designed to work element-wise on arrays of equal length (which strings often aren't). String comparisons should normally use [`strcmp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html). However, to check if a string is empty you should just use [`isempty`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html).

...But all of that is a moot point, since you shouldn't be checking the output of [`uigetfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html) like that anyway. When the user cancels file selection, the outputs of `uigetfile` are all set to `0`, so your `if` statement should look like this:

```
if isequal(filename, 0)
  % if the imagePath is empty, display a error message
  h = msgbox('Invalid Value', 'Error','error');
else
  % obtain image-file's path
  imagePath = fullfile(pathname, filename); % NOTICE I MOVED THIS INSIDE THE IF STATEMENT!
  ...
  % All the other stuff you want to do
  ...
end
```